# Display JSON results from REST API

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, rest, sharepoint-hosted-app

I have the following code

```
function execCrossDomainRequest() {

var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);


executor.executeAsync({
    url: appweburl + "/_api/Web/GetUserById(9)",
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
    success: successHandler,
    error: errorHandler
});


}

function successHandler(data) {
var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data.body);
var announcementsHTML = "";
var results = jsonObject.d.results;


 var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data.body);
var announcementsHTML = "";
var results = jsonObject.d.results;

for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    announcementsHTML = announcementsHTML +
        "<p><h1>" + results.Title +
        "</h1>" + results.Email +
        "</p><hr>";

}



document.getElementById("renderAnnouncements").innerHTML = announcementsHTML;

}
```

Which should give me the user details back out of SP but instead i keep getting an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this way to create a RequestExecutor:

```
function execCrossDomainRequest() {
    var executor;
    executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
    executor.executeAsync(
        {
            url:
                appweburl +
                "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/GetUserById(1)?@target='" +
                hostweburl + "'",
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            success: successHandler,
            error: errorHandler
        }
    );
}

function successHandler(data) {
    var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data.body);

    document.getElementById("userId").innerHTML =
        "<b>" + jsonObject.d.Title + "</b>";
}
```

I got my user name by this way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
                function successHandler(data) {
                var jsonOBJ2 = $.parseJSON(data.d);
                $.each(jsonOBJ2, function (i, item) {

                });
```